# Using Wcf with gzip compression

Tags: wcf, gzip, wcf-client, compression

We have a wcf service that takes large amount of data. As a requirement we want to take the request objects gzipped and response them using the same compression. How can I do this? I couldn't find any document describing  this issue.

How can I develop a wcf soap service that works like that and how to consume this kind of services?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Microsoft has a sample that demonstrates this (you can compile their code, and simply plug it into your application)

[GZip Encoder Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138373%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

There is a more complete sample in the WCF/WF/Cardspace samples here:

[Windows Communication Foundation Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751450%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

If you look in WCF/Extensibility/MessageEncoder/Compression, there is a more complete sample with an example client and server

Comment: I downloaded the sample code, there is only a .cs file. How can I plug it into my application? To the service library project or consumer project? And sending the service requests will be the same as the version without gzip compression? Can you give some more details?

Answer (score 1):

Good article : [HTTP COMPRESSION in IIS 6 and IIS 7 using Service Account](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpCompression)

Check : [HTTP Compression](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpCompression)

[Enable Gzip compression in IIS 6.0 for ASP.NET 2.0 websites](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31073/Enable-Gzip-compression-in-IIS-6-0-for-ASP-NET-2-0)

[image]

Comment: Just doing these settings mentioned in the links will be enough or is it just for the outgoing messages? If not, will the consumer call the service in the same way?