# Compress all traffic to WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, compression

We have a couple of WCF (data) services. Because few of our clients are connecting to those services via a terrible network connection, we would like to assure that **ALL** traffic is compressed. So, we would like to compress each request and response to the server **automatically**.

We use IIS 8 right now and **.NET 4+**.

How can we do that in the most natural way? (Via XML configs etc.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9130213/using-wcf-with-gzip-compression

Comment: @Snoopy Thank you, but I see only .NET 3.0/3.5, is it also for .NET 4+, aren't there any new changes?

Comment: it is still compatible. maybe there is out of the box support now, but i still use this way with .net 4.0

Comment: @Martin - If its for .NET 4+ then it supports the version of .NET you are using.  I don't understand your question.  .NET 4.5 is the highest version of .NET as of 2012.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

.NET 4.5 introduces GZIP compression out of the box
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751889.aspx

See the CompressionFormat values

Comment: They are using IIS 8 and .NET 4.0+ so why mention the fact 3.5 doesn't support compression?

Comment: I should have thought to look I aplogize.